# Can you include html in word replacements?

Tags: civicontribute, error

We have a contribution page, it says the following when credit cards are declined:

Your payment was not successful. Please try again

we want it to say:

Your payment was not successful. Please try again. If you continue to have issues, please email us.

When I use `<a href="mailto:email@mail.com">email us</a>` the word replacement gets garbles the input.

Is there another option?

Answer (score 1):

There's a WIP PR (work-in-progress code change) that if I remember right while reviewing it made it mostly work, but I do think html is iffy right now.

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/15836#issuecomment-553702913

You could do it with an extension that just inserts some jquery that appends your text to the existing `<div>`. https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/region/